# Request $http.jsonp get values in ANgularJS

Tags: angularjs, web-services, jsonp, angular-services

I'm trying to understand and doing some small modification in a project.It's on `AngularJS jsonp` registration form.previously form had first name,last name...like many inputs.but i want user to enter email,pw and confirm password only.then i've removed unwanted input fields from html file and tried to sign up.but my registration is not working.if success full respond (registered: 1) my function should redirect to profile page.

**Reg.html**

```
<form ng-submit="signUp()">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="email" type="email" ng-model="user.email" required class="form-control" name="email">
 </div>
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.pwd" required class="form-control" >
 </div>
 <div class="input-group last-child">
              <input type="password" ng-model="user.cpwd" required class="form-control" >
 </div>
 <button class="btn" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

**Login.js controller**

```
myApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, $window,  Common, localStorageService, SweetAlert) {

$scope.user = {
    user_id : "",
    first_name : "",
    last_name : "",
    dob : "",
    mobile : "",
    gender : "",
    email : "",
    pwd : "",
    profile_img : ""
  };

$scope.signUp = function () {


    Common.get('mobile/update_profile', $scope.user, function (res, err) {
      //$window.alert(" "+jSON.stringify(res));
      if (res.user_id > 0) {

          localStorageService.set("user", res);
          $rootScope.$emit('profileChanged', function () {
          $window.location.href = '#/' + profile;
          $window.location.reload();
        });
      } else {
        SweetAlert.error("Sign Up request failed, please check the details and try again.", {
          title : "Sign Up Failed!",
          confirmButtonColor : '#e74c3c'
        });
      }
    }, true);
  };
});
```

**Common.js**

```
myApp.factory('Common', function ($http,$window) {

return {
    get : function (url, data, callback) {

      try {

        var req = {};
        req.jsonpCallbackParam = 'callback';
        req.params = data;
        $http.jsonp(window.API_URL + url, req).then(function (response) {
          if (response.data) {
           callback(response.data, {});
           $window.alert("mail "+JSON.stringify(response.data));
          } else {
            callback({}, "Some Error Occured");

          }
        });

      } catch (err) {
        callback({}, err.message);

      }
    }

});
```

postman client api and common.js alert return bellow respond

[image]

Chrome `console` error message

[image]

Comment: I don't see signUp() method in your controller. And one more thing JSONP is used get data from server. I think you should use post method to pass the data to server

Comment: sorry i have edited my post

Comment: just use window.location.href ="your-redirect-url" and see is it redirecting

Comment: i have set `alert` on response.service return empty.but when i tried with all input fields `alert` showing response.

Comment: i have updated my post chrome console showing `Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":false,"status":404,"config":` error